# Conditionally set the allowed IsIn decorator possibilities?

Tags: javascript, npm, class-validator

I have 2 fields: `field` and `subField` defined as so:

```
  @IsString()
  @IsIn(['A', 'B'])
  field: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsIn(['a', 'b', 'bb'])
  subField: string;
```

Currently, `subField` can either be `'a'` or `'b'` or `bb`. This is not what I want. If `field == 'A'`, then `subField` can only be `'a'`, and if `field == 'B'`, the subField can only be `'b'` or `'bb'`. It seems this validation would need to be asynchronous as I need to wait for `field` to get assigned a value. How can I do this async validation?

Comment: This is EXACTLY it: https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#custom-validation-decorators